# How to refresh SSIS package name?

Tags: ssis, bids

I have a template package that I copied and changed some of the parameters, the problem I'm facing now that its keep picking up the template name "Template1.dtsx" even though I renamed it to something more meaningful in solution explorer, but it keeps picking the old name. Is it possible to change this?

Comment: Right-click on package > Exclude From Project. Open package in file explorer and rename it. Open back Visual Studio, right-click on project > Add > Existing Package and select your package with a new name, Magic.